# download image and add post meta value after post publish

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I have basicly generate my web pages qr code via google apis. Here is my basic qr Code generator function.

```
function istanbulThhemesQrCodeAction( $width = '130', $height = '130', $url = null, $choe = 'UTF-8', $type = 'qr') { 
    if(empty($url)){
        $url = get_permalink(); 
    }
    $title = get_the_title();
    echo '<div class="qrCodeOfPage"><h5>Sayfanın Qr Kodu</h5><img src="'.THEMEURL.'/assets/blank.gif" data-echo="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=' . $type . '&chs=' . $width . 'x' . $height . '&chl=' . htmlspecialchars($url) . '&choe=' . $choe . '" alt="' . $title . '" class="fatihtoprak_com_toolTip" title="Bu kodu barkod okuyucusu ile okutup mobil cihazlardan da kolaylıkla erişim sağlayabilirsiniz." /></div>';
}
```

when i call this function on my single php; the qr code generated succesfully. But it is an external image. I want to download it(qr code image) in to my server called like post-name.jpg than, i want to write this image path into the custom meta field. Like http://example.com/images/qrcodes/postname.jpg

Who can help me about this ?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you wanting someone to write this code for you?  Have you made an attempt to do this yourself and are running into problems?